# Management of TFS test plan regarding a new iteration

Tags: testing, tfs, azure-devops

In TFS Test Hub, I have a reference test plan in which some hundred of test cases are ordered and sorted in a hierarchy of folders:

```
- FrontOffice

 -- UserManagement

      --- TestCase 1234

      --- TestCase 5678

- BackOffice

  -- etc.
```

When a new iteration has to be tested, I have two choices:

1- Add existing test cases in a new Test Plan, which is good, but make me lose the folder Hierarchy

2- Clone the reference test plan, which preserves the folders, but makes clones of the test cases

In this last case, the link with the requirement is second order: 
Requirement --TestedBy -> ReferenceTestCase --Cloned-> ThisIterationTestCase

Option #1 is good for reporting, but tedious for execution

[image: Option 1, test exported with link to requirement]

Option #2 is good for execution, but makes it impossible to query test results bounded to a requirement

[image: Option 2, test exported with link to the original test]

Do you guys have any advice regarding this situation?

Comment: No clear that you said it impossible to query test results bounded to a requirement, what's the different with option #1? How do you want to query test results?

Comment: HI @starianchen-MSFT, I just added exports snapshots, is that more clear for you?

Comment: Would this extension with the option to clone requirements help? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer

Comment: Do you mean the linked Requirement is missing? Do you want the test case still linked to the old requirement? If not, you can check Clone Requirement option when clone test plan (will create a new work item).

Comment: Hi, cloning the requirement is not an option, it would be too messy @WouterdeKort yes, I know about this extension, it has the behaviour exposed in the question, as has the Test Manager client tool

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can create test suites programmatically through REST API or client API (the structure can be defined in a JSON or xml file):

[Create a test suite](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/suites#create-a-test-suite)

[The Test Management API – Part 2: Creating & Modifying Test Plans](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/densto/2010/03/03/the-test-management-api-part-2-creating-modifying-test-plans/)